# Image is not sending on gmail in Asp .net Mvc using SmtpMail

Tags: model-view-controller, c#-3.0

I am trying to achieve the image which i am having base64 format, just want to send in gmail using Smtp server. the problem if the user mail is outlook then the expected result is coming but in gmail it is not coming my expected result . I tried many methods but i cant able to do please help me . I am attaching my Code below

public static string SendMail(MailInfo mail)
{
try
{

```
            string requestData =
                string.Format("client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&scope=https://outlook.office365.com/.default&grant_type=client_credentials",
                    _clientId, _clientSecret);

            string tokenUri = string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/v2.0/token", _tenant);
            string responseText = _postString(tokenUri, requestData);

            OAuthResponseParser parser = new OAuthResponseParser();
            parser.Load(responseText);

            string officeUser = _userName;
            var server = new SmtpServer(_host);
            server.Protocol = ServerProtocol.ExchangeEWS;
            server.User = officeUser;
            server.EWSImpersonatedUser = officeUser;

            server.Password = parser.AccessToken;
            server.AuthType = SmtpAuthType.XOAUTH2;
            server.ConnectType = SmtpConnectType.ConnectSSLAuto;

            var mailmsg = new SmtpMail("TryIt");

            mailmsg.From = officeUser;

            if (!mail.ToAddress.Contains(";"))
                mailmsg.To.Add(mail.ToAddress);
            else
            {
                var toList = mail.ToAddress.Split(';');
                foreach (var toMail in toList)
                    mailmsg.To.Add(toMail);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mail.CcAddress))
            {
                if (!mail.CcAddress.Contains(";"))
                    mailmsg.Cc.Add(mail.CcAddress);
                else
                {
                    var ccList = mail.CcAddress.Split(';');
                    foreach (var ccMail in ccList)
                        mailmsg.Cc.Add(ccMail);
                }
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mail.BccAddress))
            {
                if (!mail.BccAddress.Contains(";"))
                    mailmsg.Bcc.Add(mail.BccAddress);
                else
                {
                    var bccList = mail.BccAddress.Split(';');
                    foreach (var bccMail in bccList)
                        mailmsg.Bcc.Add(bccMail);
                }
            }

            mailmsg.Subject = mail.Subject;
            //mailmsg.HtmlBody = mail.Message;

            var extractionResult = ExtractImageSource(mail.Message);
            string imageSource ="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";
            // Convert base64 string to bytes
            byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageSource);

            // Convert bytes to a data URL
            string dataUrl = $"data:image/jpeg;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes)}";

            // Add the HTML body to the mail message with the embedded image using data URL
            mailmsg.HtmlBody = $"<div><img src='{dataUrl}' alt='Trulli'></div>";



            var smtp = new EASendMail.SmtpClient();

            smtp.SendMail(server, mailmsg);


        }
        catch (Exception ep)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ep.ToString());
        }
        return "Success";
    }
    static (string HtmlContent, string ImageSource) ExtractImageSource(string html)
    {
        // Define the regular expression pattern
        string pattern = "<img\\s+[^>]*?src\\s*=\\s*['\"](.*?)['\"][^>]*?>";

        // Use Regex to match the pattern
        Match match = Regex.Match(html, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // Check if a match is found
        if (match.Success)
        {
            // Extract the image source value
            string imageSource = match.Groups[1].Value;

            // Remove the img tag from the HTML content
            string modifiedHtml = Regex.Replace(html, pattern, string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            // Return the modified HTML content and the extracted image source
            return (HtmlContent: modifiedHtml, ImageSource: imageSource);
        }

        // If no match is found, return the original HTML content and an empty image source
        return (HtmlContent: html, ImageSource: string.Empty);
    }
```

[enter image description her](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOlFC.png)

my current output i paste above please see . My need is I need to share the image in gmail Please tell me solution